# Auto send SMS to phone number after getting result from QR Code

Tags: android, sms, qr-code

I'm new to Android/Java development. I'm trying to make an app in Android Studio that scans a QR Code and sends the scanned data automatically to a phone number. So far I have source code from a QR code Scanner I got from Github, runs well but it only scans and can't get it to send the scanned data, what code do I need to add for that to happen. Thanks

Here is the Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CodeScannerView scannerView = findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
    mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(this, scannerView);
    mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                    
                }
            });
        }
    });
    scannerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCodeScanner.startPreview();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCodeScanner.startPreview();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mCodeScanner.releaseResources();
    super.onPause();
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should get a code snippet for sending sms anywhere in google search as you did for `QRCode scanner` part. Here is below if it helps.

```java
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
String phoneNo;// make sure to put your phone number here
String message;

protected void sendSMSMessage() {       
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
         Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
               Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            } else {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
      }
   }

@Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
      switch (requestCode) {
         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
               && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                  "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return;
            }
         }
      }

   }
```

Then call the `sendSMSMessage("12312312", message);` when you receive the scanned code result. Or like below:

```java
mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    message = result.getText();
                    sendSMSMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                    
                }
            });
        }
    });
```